# Java how to make the given piece display the whole row, not just the last word where it remained

Tags: java

This code finds the first word "horror", but does not show me the whole line, only the word found.

```
File f = new File("MyFile.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scan.next();
    if (str.contains("horror")) {
        System.out.println(str + " este horror");
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the line with ``String str = scan.nextLine();``

Answer (score 2):

The `Scanner` class has many methods for reading different types, and each has a corresponding `hasNext...()` method, for example `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()`. You checked `hasNextLine()`, but used `next()` which returns the next *word* instead of `nextLine()` which returns the next *line*.

Change your code from:

```
String str = scan.next(); // read next word ❌
```

to:

```
String str = scan.nextLine(); // read next line ✅
```

Comment: Upvoting also because of the ❌✅ 